# Display Toast in doInBackground when I have exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast, android-toast

I want to display a Toast in my background thread in the doInBackground method. Of course, this doesn't work. So I tried this

```
int error = 1;
publishProgress(error);
Log.i ( "InternetConnection" , "Loading Internet from Cache not working because of no Internet connection." );
return null;
```

And the onProgressUpdate method is

```
protected void onProgressUpdate ( Integer integers ){
    if ( integers == 1){
        Toast.makeText ( c.getApplicationContext(), "Daten konnten nicht geladen werden.", 0).show();
    }
}
```

Isn't it right, that when I call publishProgress the onProgressUpdate is used?

C is by the way my activity, so

`Context c = MainActivity();`

How can I possibly show a Toast, because with this code it's not showing up.

Comment: use log, or send your data to postExecute to display on ui

Comment: I'm logging. It should be visible for the user who can't see the logs. A Toast would be the thing I would likek to do. Wouldn't like to display it as a static text to the user.

Comment: @Rohit You can handle UI stuff in the `onProgressUpdate()` method which also runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Display Toast in doInBackground when I have exception

**onProgressUpdate()** method takes *array of T objects* (generally), in your case *array of Integers*.

You need to correct your method! Now it's not override super class method. Ten you are passing into this method number 1 so you need to correct your method.

The method have to looks like this:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... integers) {
    int value = integers[0];
   if (value == 1) {
      // show your Toast    
   }
}
```

And now it should works.

Please have a look carefully at [AsyncTask docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Put the log in doInBackground itself but use `Handlers` to do so.

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                               //your logs here.
                            }
                        });
```